# Adding a small, custom icon and popup to a title of Google Charts

Tags: javascript, html, charts, google-visualization

I'm using Google's Column and Bar charts https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/

All is fine except one thing: I want to add a small "i" icon next to a title of a chart. When I click **or** move a mouse over it, a custom popup should appear with some information.

Let's take this example https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/columnchart

```
 var options = {
    title: 'Motivation and Energy Level Throughout the Day',
```

I want that i-icon and popup which will appear to be placed right after the end of the title "...the Day"

I've gone through the documentation but haven't found anything. Is there a way to implement this?

*P.S.
Or perhaps there's a way to get a similar result, that is, place i-icon somewhere else on a chart? But it should be related to a whole chart.*

Comment: @WhiteHat, that won't work for me, overlay is for some other goal --> it's always visible and is like a watermark --> not what I need.

Comment: @WhiteHat, and a popup?

Comment: @WhiteHat, ok, but the thing is: how can I make a popup to appear when a mouse is over an i-icon regardless of what kind of popup it is?

Comment: @WhiteHat, I mean I won't have control of a mouse being over an "overlay" or when a mouse is clicking on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use an [overlay](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/overlays) to place an "information" icon on the chart

then use css to show a "tooltip" when the icon is hovered

see following working snippet,
the overlay is placed within the chart's `'ready'` event

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['controls', 'corechart', 'table']
}).then(function () {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('timeofday', 'Time of Day');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Motivation Level');
  data.addRows([
    [{v: [8, 0, 0], f: '8 am'}, 1],
    [{v: [9, 0, 0], f: '9 am'}, 2],
    [{v: [10, 0, 0], f:'10 am'}, 3],
    [{v: [11, 0, 0], f: '11 am'}, 4],
    [{v: [12, 0, 0], f: '12 pm'}, 5],
    [{v: [13, 0, 0], f: '1 pm'}, 6],
    [{v: [14, 0, 0], f: '2 pm'}, 7],
    [{v: [15, 0, 0], f: '3 pm'}, 8],
    [{v: [16, 0, 0], f: '4 pm'}, 9],
    [{v: [17, 0, 0], f: '5 pm'}, 10],
  ]);

  var options = {
    hAxis: {
      title: 'Time of Day',
      format: 'h:mm a',
      viewWindow: {
        min: [7, 30, 0],
        max: [17, 30, 0]
      }
    },
    legend: {
      alignment: 'end',
      position: 'bottom'
    },
    title: 'Motivation and Energy Level Throughout the Day',
    vAxis: {
      title: 'Rating (scale of 1-10)',
      ticks: [
        {v: 8.5, f: 'A'},
        {v: 4.5, f: 'B'},
        {v: 2, f: 'C'}
      ]
    }
  };

  var container = document.getElementById('chart');
  var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(container);

  google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
    var chartLayout = chart.getChartLayoutInterface();
    var chartPosition = $('#chart').position();
    var titleLeft = 24;
    var titlePosition = chartLayout.getBoundingBox('title');
    $('#chart-overlay').css({
      left: (chartPosition.left + titlePosition.left - titleLeft) + 'px',
      top: (chartPosition.top + titlePosition.top) + 'px'
    }).removeClass('hidden');
  });

  chart.draw(data, options);
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}

.overlay:hover .popup {
  display: inline-block;
}

.popup {
  background-color: #fff9c4;
  border: 1px solid #ffd54f;
  display: none;
  padding: 6px;
}

.popup span {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="hidden overlay" id="chart-overlay">
  <div>
    <img alt="Information" src="http://findicons.com/files/icons/2166/oxygen/16/dialog_information.png" />
  </div>
  <div class="popup">
    <div>
      <span>Information:</span>
    </div>
    <div>
      This is the information for the tooltip...
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="chart"></div>
```